# How to make click event.target live?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I'm developing pop-up button, so I designed code

`$(event.target).click(function() {
            window.open("/widget/dialog", "", "");
});`

However, it doesn't work when I click first time. It works well when I click second time. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is this called from?

Comment: I'm using meteor, so I called it form
`Template.Button.events({
    'click button': function(event, template) {
        $(event.target).click(function() {
            window.open("/widget/dialog", "");
        });
   }
});`

Answer (score 0):

> However, it doesn't work when I click first time.

That's because the first time the handler is executed it **binds** (not executes!) *another* event handler that calls `window.open("/widget/dialog", "", "")`.

Now you have *two* event handlers bound to the element and both will be executed when you click a second time. But that also means that *yet another* event handler will be bound, so after the second click, *three* event handlers will be bound to the element.

---

If you want it to work "the first time", then do what you want to do in the "outer" event handler. Do not bind another event handler in the handler. Forget about `$(event.target).click(...)`.

```
Template.Button.events({
  'click button': function(event, template) {
    window.open("/widget/dialog", "");
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And opens 2 windows when clicked the third time?(May be blocked by browser) Then you haven't understand what is an event listener.

I guess your code is like this: (because snippets doesn't allow popups, I showed using `console.log`)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hh").click(function() {
    $(event.target).click(function() {
      console.log("Hello!");
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hh" type="button" value="google" />
```

If so, you are in trouble because you are binding event listeners in event listeners.

To say in detail, let me first make some name up: The outer `$("#hh").click` is called ELA (Event Listener A), while the inner `$(event.target).click` is ELB.

1. Before your first click, on button: ELA, thus on click, ELB is bound.
2. After 1st click, before 2nd, on button: ELA+ELB, thus popped up and another ELB is bound.
3. 2nd - 3rd, ELA+ELB*2, click cause 2 popups and another ELB is binded.

See? This causes horror.

The correct way is this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hh").click(function() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hh" type="button" value="google" />
```

This will make one `console.log` each time you click.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below example. 

Hope this helps. I have removed `.target` to the event

click this link, https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/Lpj2fanw/15/

JQUERY

```
var event = $('a');

$(event).click(function() {
  window.open("/widget/dialog", "", "");
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#">Click Here</a>
```